# Not sufficient permissions to change permissions

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk, permission, apple-silicon

I have M1 macbook air and trying to connect to external hd (Seagate 1K9AP6-502) in NTFS. I can read files on the drive, but I can't write. For example `nano` gives me an error that it's a read-only drive. I can read and write if I plug it into any of my linux machines.

I have tried `COMMAND + I` to change permissions of the drive. I can see that my own user has read + write, staff and everyone have only read. If I `ls -l` I see that group owner in staff and my user is the owner.

I don't understand what is wrong. What do you suggest to do to access external hd?

Comment: What format is the drive?

Comment: @mmmmmm NTFS is the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really a permissions issue. macOS cannot write to NTFS natively, only read.

You can get a reliable NTFS 'write enabler' from Paragon - [Paragon NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/)

There's also a free version from [MacFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io). I've never tried this one, but reports are split on how well it works.